# Как заставить пример работать в IE?

Tags: css3, вёрстка

```css
#block {
  background: #000;
  clip-path: polygon(0% 0%,100% 0%,100% 75%,63% 75%,50% 81%,37% 75%,0% 75%);
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0% 0%,100% 0%,100% 75%,63% 75%,50% 81%,37% 75%,0% 75%);
  width: 100%;
  height: 900px;
}
```

```html
<div id="block"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

IE не поддерживает [clip-path](http://caniuse.com/#search=clip-path), так что ни как. Можно попробовать способ приведенный в коде.

```css
.triangle {
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  background: black;
  min-height: 900px;
}
.triangle::after,
.triangle:after {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 60px 100px 0 100px;
  border-color: black transparent transparent transparent;
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="triangle"></div>
```

Comment: но есть же inline svg? я пробовал, но проблема в том, что он не поддерживает проценты в координатах или поддерживает?

Answer (score 1):

В Firefox ваш пример тоже не работает.

Но в принципе нет никакой проблемы сделать его в SVG

```html
<svg width="100%" height="900" viewBox="0 0 100 100" preserveAspectRatio="none">
  <!-- Этот rect показывает реальный размер SVG -->
  <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="lavender" />
  <!-- Вот ваш прямоугольник с хвостиком -->
  <path d="M0,0 H100 V75 H63 L50,81 37,75 H0 Z" fill="rebeccapurple" />
</svg>
```

Comment: Но нужен именно блок, иначе как я буду верстать содержимое? Спрашиваю потому, что предстоит сверстать это: https://yadi.sk/i/GENIQ0kotsJAS

Comment: А что будет внутри-то?

Comment: Текст будет, я просто для наглядности из шаблона его убрал

Comment: Ну положите этот svg в фон

Comment: а как это сделать?